# SQL Server Compact Edition not showing records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

my application registers new users to a compact database, embedded in the application. When i register users, it allows them to log in, but it does not show in the database? I look at the database, and there is only one row containing null values. Can anyone help, is there a setting ive missed (something about rebinding or something)? Please help

Comment: How are you updating the table ?

Comment: It is a common scenario. Are you looking at your table using Server Manager with a connection to the file in the project folder? What is your actual connection string (the one used in code)? Are the two the same?

Comment: ive sorted it by moving the database to my debug folder. Now, how can i build an installer that copies that database to the clients computer as well??

Comment: See my latest blog post for ideas